# AngularJS - Get image from a URL and display it HTML side

Tags: html, angularjs

In my Angular application, I am getting the image name from the database and then storing it in local storage when a user logs in.

Now after login, the page to be redirected is loaded without the application being refreshed.

And on that page, I want to show the image which I have stored in local storage.

```
if (localStorage.getItem('logo') != undefined) 
        $rootScope.logo = "http://somewebsite.com/"+localStorage.getItem('logo');
```

Now, in HTML,

```
<img src="{{logo}}" >
```

So the problem is, when I login, even if the image name is there in local storage, the image is being displayed as broken. and when I reload the application, it shows the image.
So I concluded that the URL of the file is not being called because the application is not being reloaded after login.

So is there any method through which I can load the image without reloading the application?

Comment: Mmmhh.. ng-src? https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-src.asp

Comment: Not working brother

Comment: Did you try to output the logo variable? it exists?

Comment: this : http://jsfiddle.net/ztrLpa3w/1/ is working pretty fine, idk what you're doing wrong...

Comment: yes the logo variable exists.. also your fiddle will obviously work fine because when you press the run button in fiddle, the page will be reloaded. @Julo0sS

Comment: I'm Sorry I can't post the plunkr because my files has thousands of lines of code. and I only have one issue which I have mentioned clearly. @WilliamHampshire

Comment: Did you try using "ng-init" on your template to set the variable? If I get it right, you have a template for login, using the "mainController", and once your login is effective, you switch template using the same controller. Right?

Comment: No, I'm sorry but what is that?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/angular/ng_ng-init.asp

Comment: Okay I'll check that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152051/discussion-between-julo0ss-and-rahul-jain).

Comment: @RahulJain create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) then...

Comment: okay, I'll post it @WilliamHampshire

Comment: Check this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/IgorMinar/ADukg/     ... It'll work fine bcoz the page is reloaded when we run it.

Comment: If the example works fine then what is the problem?

Comment: From the comments, it is clear that you do not yet have an answerable question. Please [edit] it to add a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

First, use **`ng-src`** instead of **`src`**, other thing is check if the image exists and then load it

```
<div ng-if="logo">
    <img ng-src="{{logo}}" >
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, image exists... and no, ng-src also not working

Comment: where are you setting the image?

Comment: image is in cloud. the name of image is stored in localstorage.. so I am appending the imagename to the url and storing it in the `$scope.logo`.. It is displaying the image only after I reload the page